# ROR ActiveRecord attribute handling with a callback before_update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, beforeupdate

This code produces an **ActiveRecordError**:

> Callbacks must be a symbol denoting
>   the method to call, a string to be
>   evaluated, a block to be invoked, or
>   an object responding to the callback
>   method."

```
before_update :check_instock, :unless => Proc.new { |inventory| inventory.needed.nil? } 

def check_instock
  if needed < amount
    instock = true
  else
    instock = false
  end
end
```

This code is placed in my inventory model, I'm trying to handle some logic prior to calling  @inventory.update_attributes (controller). Previously I was calling @inventory.update_attributes multiple times, which resulted in code that [worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760224/unfortunately-this-works-ror-comparison-in-activerecord-update), albeit not succinctly.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
before_update :set_instock, :unless => :inventory_not_needed?

private

def set_instock
  self.instock = (needed < amount) ? true : false
end

def inventory_not_needed?
  needed.nil?
end
```